# SweetAlert 2 - How to declare a function to run before the html property

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I am declaring few buttons inside an html property of a SweetAlert2 window.
I need when each button is clicked to run the test() function.
Where can I declare it?

```
const {value: formValues} = await this.$swal.fire({
    title: 'Select Button',
    html:'<button id="btn1" class="swal2-cancel swal2-styled " onclick="test()">Button1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="swal2-cancel swal2-styled " onclick="test()">Button2</button>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the function on the global scope.

For example:

```
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test() {
            ...
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @Shahzad, I didn't mention - I'm inside a vue js app. Is it ok to add a function to the window object ?

Comment: @YalonKeret, yes there shouldn't be any issues with that. Try it

Comment: @YalonKeret, please accept (tick) the answer

Comment: I did of course. I'm in stackoverflow level which my ticking isn't visible yet